# MS-Charts Zooming in Secondary Y axis

Tags: .net, winforms, mschart

I am new to MS-Charts. So kindly excuse me if in case the question is inappropriate.

I am using line-type series data. I have also enabled zooming in the chart. I have an option where the user can select a particular series and shift it from primary Y-axis to Secondary Y-axis. But in this case, while i zoom the chart the axis labels in the secondary axis does not dynamically change with zooming. However the zooming works fine. Also, the axis labels get dynamically updated while the series is in the primary axis.

I tried using the code:

```
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY2.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
```

But it doesn't help much.Any suggestions?